# How to create new work items in TFS with WIQL

Tags: windows, tfs, azure-devops, desktop-application, wiql

I´m creating a desktop application (WinForms C#) for my team which enables to manage some basic operations with TFS as like create tasks, bugs and user stories. The main idea is to make this management process faster... However, I found how to get the work items by using WIQL but I don´t know if it's posible to create new work items using WIQL... I have not idea how to do that, so I don't have code to show you. I just know how to GET, but I don't know how to create CREATE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. WIQL stands for *work item **query** language*. It's for querying, not for creating.

If you want to create work items, you'll have to either use the Extended Client object model for C# or directly invoke the REST APIs, both of which are thoroughly documented.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Mann, that information is enough for me. 
Now I will investigate about it.

Comment: It is documented here (for API version 4.1):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1